# Best way to add a new Node a existing Corda blockchain

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am new to blockchain and currently doing POC for learning and some solution.
I want to add a new node to my existing Corda blockchain. e.g
I have 3 nodes A, B, C, and one Notary, I want to add another node D. below are my questions:

- 1> Best way to add a new node.
- 2> Do I need to change the code as I need to maintain the ledger with D as well?
- 3> Is it possible through configurations?

Any best practices. Looking forward for some help.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way to add a new node is to use the Corda node tool.
2. You will need to change the code if you want to include the new node in the ledger.
3. It is possible to add a new node through configurations.

Comment: thanks for the response, do you have any reference for the node tool?